# Ajax permalink in wordpress Pluto Theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress, permalinks

Having an issue with a wp theme and creator can't seem to help. It's Ajax driven and doesn’t support custom permalink...

So as soon as the website appeared on Google all link referred send to some black page which seem to be out of the website:

Link appearing in Google: www.thaiorchid.be/menus/ (black page)
Compared to the real webpage: www.thaiorchid.be/#menu-item-21

I start to have an idea of solution with: [AJAX navigation in Wordpress - Trouble with Permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865770/ajax-navigation-in-wordpress-trouble-with-permalinks-solved) and tried it on the contact page www.thaiorchid.be/contact which doesn't redirect to the black page anymore but it's still not perfect compared to www.thaiorchid.be/#menu-item-19...

Any idea would be really welcome. 
Thanks a lot, 
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site does not provide an appropriate fallback for non–JS browsers (e.g. most Google bots to my knowledge). This seems a (serious) shortcoming of the theme without knowing it any further.

If built properly, an “AJAX–enhanced” site like this should allow access to **all** content through basic HTML requests. If Javascript is available in a client, preferably the same content should be loaded using AJAX requests, allowing e.g. for faster page loads and nice transitions.

Another problem comes from a missing sub navigation. Since your sub menu (fly-out) is not available without Javascript, you would need to provide an alternative way to reach pages two levels deep and deeper.

Here's an example on how this page could/should work without Javascript:

```
1. Visit homepage
2. Click “Menus” in navigation
3. Opens “Menus” page, showing what the “black page” currently shows 
   + proper header/footer 
   + main navigation 
   + sub navigation for all elements in “Menus” fly–out (“Potages, Entrées, …”)
4. Click “Potages”
5. View “Potages” page, again with proper 
   header/footer 
   + main navigation 
   + sub navigation for all elements in “Menus” fly–out
```

---

I know, you’re looking probably for a quick solution, maybe a snippet of code or a plugin to resolve your situation. Unfortunately — unless your theme provides you with some help — such a silver bullet doesn’t exist. The current implementation simply approaches the topic of an “AJAX site” in a fairly reckless way IMHO (you will be “happy” to know, that most screen readers won’t be able to access your content either) and until you re–build the theme or fix the structure you’re pretty much stuck with an unaccessible site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @PolarBlau. Agreed about the non–JS browsers and accessibility issues. It's too reckless for my taste and quite surprise the author didn't pay attention at all to those issues. If I keep on with this one I'll create an alternative navigation. _Oh another question if you still have time:_ What would be the best way to redirect all good url like (www.thaiorchid.be/contact) to the ajax version like (www.thaiorchid.be/#menu-item-19). Thousands thanks again.