# Best solution to redirect URLs to an Ajax version?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

Further question about [Ajax permalink in wordpress Pluto Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739926/ajax-permalink-in-wordpress-pluto-theme)

So it's a fully Ajax Wordpress theme, all URLs appearing in Google are not from the user version website but the 'underneath' version of it.

Example: 
Link appearing in Google: www.thaiorchid.be/menus/ (strange black page) Compared to the user webpage: www.thaiorchid.be/#menu-item-21

I'm searching for the best way to automatically redirect all pages (like the one /menus to the one /#menu-item-21) to at least have something presentable, any idea what would be the best solution?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Do you have access to the template file which is used to render the partial view rendered for the AJAX requests? 2. In case of e.g. `menu-item-21` -- is 21 the ID of the post/page?

Comment: For 1. yes I've access to everything. And 2. Sadly no (Menus post is number 11 (compare to Ajax URL: #menu-item-21)). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm currently not able to test the following, but I believe that something like this should work, given that the standard Wordpress menu is used within this theme.

```
// functions.php
function get_menu_id_for_post($post_id) {
  global $wpdb;
  $query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "
      SELECT post_id 
      FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
      WHERE meta_key = '_menu_item_object_id' 
      AND meta_value = %s
    ", 
    $post_id
  );
  $menu_id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
  return $menu_id;
}

function is_ajax_request() {
  return (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&   
          strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
}

// partial template, right on the top:
<?php if (!is_ajax_request()): ?>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.location = "http://www.thaiorchid.be/#menu-item-<?php echo get_menu_id_for_post($post->ID) ?>";
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will determine the correct menu ID based on the current post’s or page’s ID and then redirect using Javascript if the current page as not been loaded via AJAX.

Again, I can’t test this right now at all, but maybe it can help you to go on.

Comment: Hey @polarblau thanks again, looks like a great solution! I tried it out but still with the same results... will try some more.

Comment: Are you having the second bit in place within your template now? Could you post a link to an example?

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I did edit the page.php file and added the second part of the code but I took it back off because no page was opening anymore... But this is also written in the top of page.php code and may help? 
/**
* Get Current page object
**/
$page = get_page($post->ID);


/**
* Get current page id
**/
$current_page_id = '';

if(isset($page->ID))
{
    $current_page_id = $page->ID;
}

Comment: I quickly tried this as good as I can without the theme and a vanilla WP installation and it turns out, that I forgot to include `global $wpdb;` within `get_menu_id_for_post()`. After adding that, I'm being properly redirected. Maybe that get's you going?

Comment: Amazing this is working!!! Wow @polarblau can't thank you enough for your help... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For backwards compatibility write the links in a correct fashion but add a relation/class what ever you feel comfortable with:

```
<a href="http://example.com/path/to/file.html" rel="ajax" >link</a>
```

Then from jquery:

```
$('a[rel=ajax]').click(function(e) {
    //do whatever
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In some instances I've skipped adding the **rel="ajax"** or **class="ajax"** and just looked for links that point back to the domain of my website:

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com"]').click(function(e) {
    //do whatever
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Usually my **do whatever method** made an ajax get request to the very same addres that was in the initial link. It just added a parameter **?ajax=1** so the template could skip outputting the header/footer (when I used AHAH) or to json_encode the response (for JSON output).

Comment: Thanks @Mihai, but the links aren't written by me but auto-generated from wordpress (those are the links from pages or posts) is there a way to ass _rel="ajax"_ into those kind of links maybe?

Comment: You mean like this: **In some instances I've skipped adding the rel="ajax" or class="ajax" and just looked for links that point back to the domain of my website** ?

Comment: $('a[href^="http:// example.com"]') selects only the a tags that have a href attribute **starting with** "http:// example.com". You don't need the rel="ajax" or the class="ajax".